# How to join two DF in pandas and select the columns I want to return?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two data frames I want to join but I do not want the new df to contain all columns. How to choose only a few columns?

Ex:

```
df1.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 

df2.columns = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'j', 'h', 'p', 'o']
```

I want to join both to have:

```
df3.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'p']
```

Comment: If `cols=['a', 'b', 'c']`, then `df[cols]` slices the `df`. Slice `df1` with `cols` for `1`, then `df2` with `cols` for `2`, then just merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to join the data frames

Then, use

```
df3 = df3['a','b','c','d','e','f','p']
```